# Bash script call a function in a different file

Tags: bash

I am using bash script to call a function in a different file. But, the function didn't seem to run. I couldn't figure out what's the issue here. The following is part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source utility
res=$(InterCombinations)
```

File: utility

```
InterCombinations()
{
   ...
   echo "InterCombinations is called"
}
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: try specifying the path to the `utility`, e.g., `source ./utility`. Also make sure you are doing `echo "$res"` to verify correct execution.

Comment: Note that the file to be sourced is looked up relative to the current working directory, not the directory where the script is saved.

Comment: You should always add `set -e` to the top of your Bash scripts so that they will stop when an error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts will work provided the utility file is in the current working directory.
You could put or echo the variable:

```
set -x
```

in your main script to watch the steps in execution:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
set -x
source utility
res=$(InterCombinations)
```

You are saving the output of your called function on to a variable and not echoing/printing it on to the "stdout".